# How Can I Convert a live stream from a H.264 Encoder to a streaming service like Wowza?

Tags: networking, streaming, h.264, wowza, encoder

hoping to get some input on a streaming issue im having.

I have a H.264 hardware encoder where you connect an HDMI source (dvd player, computer etc) and then you can set up that encoder to work over WAN by opening up a port in your router and setting a port forwading rule (in my case the ip of the device is 172.16.16.121 and port using 3124)

I have set this up an am able to view the stream from the encoder using VLC > open network stream > and type in my public IP url rtsp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3124/live.sdp

but when I try giving this URL into a streaming service like Wowza, Streamedian or FlashPhoner it does not work at all.

Any ideas or suggestions on what I might be doing wrong?

Responses from Wowza

First Response: Looking at the server logs you have provided, it seems that Wowza is trying to connect to the RTSP source, but the connection is timing out.

Second Response:  It is possible that the RTSP source is not able to establish the connection over TCP, which is being used by default by Wowza. It is possible to have Wowza use UDP to connect to the RTSP live source by specifying the "rtpTransportMode" parameter and setting it to "udp". Here is an article describing how to do this:
https://www.wowza.com/docs/How-to-specify-per-stream-settings-in-stream-files#rtspstreams

Third & Latest Response: In the server logs I can still see that Wowza has problems connecting to this IP camera stream.
I will check with our engineering team and have them take a look as to why this stream cannot be ingested. I will let you knwo as soon as I have any new information available.

Responses from Streamedian

We tested your stream. There mpeg2ts goes on rtp. The player does not support it in this form.
Therefore, your stream is not shown. To support it we need about 2 weeks.
Unfortunately we are working for another projects now.   We will back to new version of player some latter.

Answer (score 0):

In order for RTP/RTSP/RTCP to work correctly - don't be behind a firewall, your RTP source must have a valid public IP address - any NATed address won't work.